# screen - reattach last session

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Is there a way of getting screen to directly reattach to the last used session if there are multiple sessions available?

I always have at least one screen session running on my server, and always need a second one. I end up with a long list of sessions, and it would be great to just go back to the last one without running:

```
screen -r <generatedscreenname>
```

I know you can set the screen name and access it again that way, so that is not a solution for my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is `-R`

from the [screen manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Invoking-Screen.html):

> Resume the first appropriate detached screen session. If successful, all other command-line options are ignored. If no detached
>   session exists, start a new session using the specified options, just
>   as if ‘-R’ had not been specified. This option is set by default if
>   screen is run as a login-shell (actually screen uses ‘-xRR’ in that
>   case). For combinations with the ‘-D’/‘-d’ option see there.

Comment: -R didn't work for me before and still doesn't, but -RR did the trick! thanks